# What do I call the object-hierarchical "path" of JSON attributes / properties / members and what is their standardized name?

Tags: json, naming-conventions, naming

Consider I have following typed JSON objects:

```
Parent: {
    "field1" : "Value of field1"
    "fieldC" : {Child}
}

Child: {
    "field2" : "Value of field2"
}
```

**Q:** What do I call `field1` and `field2`?
Just [Strings](http://json.org/)?
**Q:** What to i call the "path" `fieldC.field2`?
Accessor path?
Field path?
Member hierarcy path?

Comment: are you asking about properties?

Comment: Maybe "property" and "object-hierarchical property path" are the answers I'm looking for. However json.org does not mention 'property', although it would make sense as JSON is "based on a subset of JS". They just call the 'fields' i'm referring to as 'names' (of a 'name/value' pair).

Answer (score 1):

`field1` and `field2` are just strings.

`[anything, ..., ... ]` is just an array, so the elements of an object.

and then you have `0`-`9` (with decimals, negative, positive or with `e`), `true`/`false` and `null`, as numeric values, boolean and nullvalue

`{Child}` is an object. I don't think it's called path (I'd say that's opinion-based). maybe field-path, but it's rather a child-object. the key is a string and the value is an object/array/string/bool/null/numeric or decimal

all the possibilities e.g.:

```
{
    "string": "string-value",
    "nulltype": null,
    "child_object": {
        "boolean": true,
        "any_decimal_int": -1.5e3
    },
    "array_values":[
        {
            "any_value": true
        },
        {
            "any_value": false
        }
    ]
}
```

of course you can combine more and have unlimited child-objects and lists :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of the key:value / name:value / string:value nature of JSON. I'm just looking for the correct way to call the "keys" (and their hierarchical path in case objects have have child objects), according to a specification preferably. You have a point tough, according to the spec, the "path" probably has no name. However I would like to have a name for the practice of "writing open" "property paths" such as fieldC.field2. Going with "property path" if something else is not proven correct : ]

Answer (score 1):

[jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/) seems to refer `field1`,`fieldC`,and `field2` as **member names**, which I find much more descriptive than just 'Strings'.

As mentioned in my comment to first answer, I guess I'll personally be using (hierarchical) **property path** or just (object) **member hierarchy** while referring to 'writing open' the object-hierarchical property/attribute/member 'path' such as `fieldC.field2`. Seems to be alot of room for interpretation in that. : ]